# Will the Activity's onResume() run forever?

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, onresume

In android, assuming that the first time I run my app, I want to have a block of code that runs (theoretically) forever assuming that the activity is always visible, should I just do the following:

```
public void onResume(){
// Block of code
}
```

or

```
public void onResume(){
while(true){
// Block of code
}
}
```

Another way of asking this would be:
In the first case, can I assume that once that block of code finishes running, that Android will re-run it again ? I tried looking for an answer for this but couldn't find any.

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, so you want a block of code that runs forever once you opened your application?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Seems like doing something like this would eat your apps memory away.

Comment: If your code will run on UI-thread, which it is by default, you will get an ANR, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onResume` runs when the activity is made visible,if you write and infinite loop inside on resume the the application will stop responding. If you have to run some code forever you should do it as a service. whatever you have to do an infinite loop is not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

No, You have to choose your second method because in your first method your block of code will get called once when there is a state transition i.e. state changes from any state(like onPause) to onResume and your block of code executed once. But after that if there is no state transition then your code will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

onResume() gets called whenever your activity is  brought to the front. This code will be called only once. If you want to re-run your code, you need to use your second approach.